# Unable to use Data Table Cucumber,

Tags: java, selenium, cucumber, cucumber-java, cucumber-junit

I`m using Cucumber Selenium and Data Table for my Login Scenario. Here is my scenario:

```html
Scenario Outline:  User login

    Given the user is on Login Page
    And   the users enter "<username>" and "<password>" 
       
   Examples:
   | username| password|
   | User_1  | passw123|
   | User_2  | passw123|
```

The first user shouldn`t log out because I`m testing limit of logged users.
For example:
1. The first user log in and stay in an app
Expected result: User successfully login
2. The second user tries to log in
Expected result: User can`t log in because of limit

But when using the second credentials, the Login page not open, the page just refreshed and displayed Homepage of the first logged user ( User_1, passw123). And I have Assertion Error:

```html
Caused by: java.lang.AssertionError: (after 5000 ms)
Expected: "Login Page"
     but: was "Home Page"
```

How can it be handled?
Thank you!

Comment: You need to add a logout step or after hook to perform the terminate the session of the first user before running the second scenario.

Comment: I can`t add this step because the test is that the first user is not logged out.

Comment: You need use a hook or background step to ensure that no users are logged in before performing a login. The step "Then the user successfully logged" remains valid as the action to logout the users is performed outside the scenario context.

Comment: @N.Hol as u say the test is not to log off the first user, then what shiuld be the expected behaviour? I dint think scenario outine is the correct way to test this case

Comment: You right, I`m not clear described my question. Now, my question updated. Maybe I should start with new browser

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You definitely should not use scenario outline for such purposes.

What you can do is:
Create one test and describe it like:
`Open login page with new browser
 And   the users enter "User1" and "password1" 
 Open login page with new browser
 And   the users enter "User2" and "password2"`

Inside step `Open login page with new browser` you should create new Instance of webdriver and set it as a main driver for all others steps.

But from my opinion use Selenium for testing such auth logic it is wrong idea, because you do not test any UI behavior, all you test is server side logic. So it would be convenient to use [Rest-assured](http://rest-assured.io/) and test that logic via http requests.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Very useful advice!

Answer (score 0):

Did you logout after your first test? In case that you are keeping your browser open, you will need to logout at the end, so you are back on the login page. Otherwise you might be redirected from the login page to homepage because there is a session active.

Comment: The test is that the first user is not logged out.

Comment: If the first user is not logged out, the browser will go to their page... If you want the second user to login again, they should start with a clean slate. (I.e. new browser, no cookies/sessions/whatever)

Comment: Yes, you right. For the second user, I should start with the new session. Thank you!

Comment: If this answered your question, could you mark the answer? Thanks!